# Problem: av_seek_frame() always returns me the beginning of the video

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to making use of FFMpeg to build a player. When I'm using av_seek_frame() to change the timestamp, it always gives me the beginning of the stream.

Here is my code:

```
bool XDemux::Seek(double pos)
{
    mux.lock();
    if (!ic)
    {
        mux.unlock();
        return false;
    }
    avformat_flush(ic);

    long long seekPos = 0;
    seekPos = ic->streams[videoStream]->duration * pos;
    int re = av_seek_frame(ic, videoStream, seekPos, AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD | AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME);
    mux.unlock();
    if (re < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Where ic and mux are defined as

```
AVFormatContext* ic
std::mutex mux;
```

When I'm trying to call the Seek function and print out the frame index, it will be something like:

```
//Read() is called:
0 0 21 42 40 ...
//Then Seek(0.9) is called, should have begin with a later frame, but it also returns me:
0 0 21 42 40 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

av_seek_frame requires position in frames, but your "seekPos" uses a time base. You need something like this to convert stream time to frames:

```
frmseekPos = av_rescale(seekPos, ic->streams[videoStream]->time_base.den, ic->streams[videoStream]->time_base.num);
frmseekPos  /= 1000;
```

Comment: As well as pointing out the issue(s) in OP's code, your answer would be better if it also contained a working code example.